# Menú corredizo (desordenado) de una página web

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema con el menú, estoy queriendo hacer un menú de una pagina web llamada LaEficazStore, al momento de desplegar el menú sale muy en desorden, alguien podría decirme que debo hacer para que salga ordenado?. mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu Desplegable</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Servicios</a>

                    <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Agrega los estilos para que se te brinde una mejor ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tu principal problema esta en que no estas usando el modelo de caja correctamente, al dejar dentro del `<li>` las etiquetas `<a>`y `<li>` pegadas.

Incorrecto:

```
<li>
    <a href="">Submenu4</a>
      <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
</li>
```

Correcto:

```html
<h1>Menu Incorrecto</h1>
<li>
   <a href="">Submenu4</a>
     <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
</li>
<hr/>
<!-- CORRECTO -->
<h1>Menu Correcto</h1>
<li>
   <span><a href="">Submenu4</a></span>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
     <li>
        <span><a href="">Submenu3</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Submenu3.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Submenu3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```